# Mule ESB and Throttling

Tags: mule, esb

IN the following link:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+ESB+3.4.0+Release+Notes

I see the following

EE-3141 When using a Throttling policy with throttling statics enabled, limit headers are swapped.

However, I can find no example of throttling policies within Mule ESB, but there is possibly a throttling policy within the Anypoint API Manager

Could someone please provide a link to how to use a Throttling policy within Mule ESB?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To achieve correct Throttling behaviour you can follow below steps:

- Configure a queue (for example, a persistent VM or a JMS queue to avoid message lost during the Mule server crash) after your inbound endpoint.
- Configure scheduled delay, for example AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY in case of ActiveMQ, to a desired value. If the queue does not support scheduled delay, then we need to find our way to achieve the delay, probably using a Java component.
- Finally, configure the outbound endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The Throttling module (which can be configured as throttler or rate limiter) comes out of the box with any Mule API Gateway distribution. Mule EE comes with a light weight version of it. If you are using Anypoint API Platform, then you don't need to pay attention to the internals of how it is being done: Simply apply/unapply the [policy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-platform-for-apis/rate-limiting-and-throttling) to your managed API and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Even i tried implementing the Throttling concept in mule flows. There is no exact way of implementation for this , but i was able get that nature into the flows using the receiver thread profiling at inbounds and dispatch threading profiles on outbound connectors.